# How to re-enable DSM web interface

Tags: synology, dsm

I managed to disable my DSM web interface and now I struggle to re-enable it. I am on DS716+. This is what I did:

From still working DSM console I disabled php 7.0 (I wanted to install version 7.2). I installed apache2.4 and changed default version in WebStation to 2.4. Then, because WebStation did not see php7.2 I figured I will restart it and perhaps it will pick up changes. Obviously after I stopped it I locked myself out.

Luckily some weeks ago I enabled ssh, so I am able to login this way. I started with restarting the box and hoping everything will come back as it was. It didn't. So I did tried restarting services (nginx, WebStation), to see it that will help. I do this:

```
root@synology:/etc# synoservice -enable nginx
root@synology:/etc# synoservice -status nginx
Service [nginx] status=[enable]
required upstart job: 
    [nginx] is start. 
=======================================
root@synology:/etc# synoservice -status pkgctl-WebStation
Service [pkgctl-WebStation] status=[disable]
required upstart job: 
    [pkgctl-WebStation] is stop. 
=======================================
root@synology:/etc# synoservice -enable pkgctl-WebStation
```

However, WebStation never starts, it just waits and waits...

I can telnet to http ports, which confirms nginx is running ok. But no page is loading, I suppose because WebStation never starts. I also tried:

```
synoservice --hard-start pkgctl-WebStation
```

with the same result (no result).

I also tried running Apache2.2 or Apache2.4 but these, similarly to WebStation are not getting up. Hence my focus on nginx.

nginx outputs this after restart (in the log file).

```
2019/07/21 14:34:53 [crit] 18247#18247: *7 connect() to unix:/run/synoscgi.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.7.143, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "scgi://unix:/run/synoscgi.sock:", host: "192.168.7.10:6003"
```

"192.168.7.10:6003" is how I used to connect to DSM from the browser.

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: I'm seeing a similar problem.  Following a restart, WebService/Apache2.4 is not running.  In my case nginx is running and I can access the web console as well as ssh access, but "synoservicectl --start pkgctl-WebStation" just hangs.  Where can I see logs with more details about why the service fails to start